# Create Access 2016 DB with VBA Code

Tags: vba, ms-access

In my main Access 2016 db, using VBA, I want to create a SEPARATE temporary Access 2016 db on the disk. Create a table inside temp db using the data i have in a CSV, then create a link in my main db to that newly created table in temp db. Now I should be able to run queries on the temp db table.

The whole thing is a little mind-boggling. So far I have below code for creating the db but it gives "Class not registered" error on line `Catalog.Create dbConnectStr` also this code is create an mdb file instead of an accdb file. Is that a problem?

```
Dim dbConnectStr As String
Dim Catalog As Object
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim dbPath As String

dbPath = "C:\TempDB.mdb"
dbConnectStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";"

'Create new database
Set Catalog = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
Catalog.Create dbConnectStr
Set Catalog = Nothing

'Connect to database and insert a new table
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
'' create table here
Set cnt = Nothing
```

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195271.aspx

Comment: Please be more clear. Do you want to create a separate database (.mdb/.accdb) file or database table in existing database? These two are entirely differently operations. And usually one does not automate the former in application code.

Comment: I want to create separate db.

Comment: @Sorceri: `.NewCurrentDatabase` opens new db in MS Access window which is not desirable.

Comment: @Kashif create a new instance of an Access Application and then call it with the new instance....viola a new DB is create and not opened in your current version of Access.......

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of creating a new DB without having it open in the current working instance of Access.

```
Sub CreateMeANewDatabasePlease(dbPathAndName As String)

Dim aApp As Access.Application

    Set aApp = New Access.Application
    aApp.NewCurrentDatabase dbPathAndName, acNewDatabaseFormatUserDefault
    aApp.Quit

End Sub

Sub StartHere()
    CreateMeANewDatabasePlease ("SomePath\TheDB.accdb")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of creating a new DB without having it open in the current working instance of Access, or creating a new temporary application instance, which is slow, and unnecessary.  This function places the file in the same folder as the DB you are using. If there is already a file there by that name, it does nothing.  In any case this function returns the full path with file name, for visual confirmation in the immediate window, for storing in your log, or just discard to a temp variable where you call it from.  You can supply a file name, or call it like ?MakeEmptyAccessFile() and it will name the file "new.accdb"

```
Function MakeEmptyAccessFile(Optional ByVal pn = "new")
    pn = Application.CurrentProject.Path + "\" + pn + ".accdb"
    If Dir(pn) = "" Then DBEngine.CreateDatabase pn, DB_LANG_GENERAL
    MakeEmptyAccessFile = pn
End Function
```